# Boxed Set of Undead Hunting Adventures Compatable with the Rules Cyclopedia

Tags: published-adventures, product-identification, dnd-becmi

During my early years of playing D&D (focused around the Rules Cyclopedia), I remember I had a set of adventures (I think it was 3?) that came in a boxed set.  They could be run separately, or the maps could link up for an epic undead hunting event.

Does this sound familiar to anyone else?  I can't remember the name, and I've always regretted not putting my friends through their paces in there (I found the whole thing a little intimidating at the time).

Comment: [There is a pretty good list of modules here, so maybe one of the name will bump your memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dungeons_%26_Dragons_modules)

Comment: Thanks @KorvinStarmast  I had looked at that before, but another pass hasn't helped, unfortunately.  I do, however, remember my friend running me through The Jade Hare way back when.

Comment: As I don't recall playing that set of modules, I can't be of any further help. I hope someone can figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

Ah hah!

On a whim, I wandered through the becmi contents over at DriveThruRPG, and my heart leapt when I saw a piece of art.  It's called "The Haunted Tower", and I now possess a PDF version.  Let the nostalgia commence.

Thanks for the help!